# Setting MySQL session variables using PDO()

Tags: php, mysql, session, pdo

I am using PHP's PDO to access my MySQL DB.  I typically create a singleton class for my connection.  I would like to set a MySQL session variable when initiating the connection, and later on as well.  See below for my failed attempts to set MySession1 and MySession2.  How can I do this?  Thanks

EDIT.  Just found out that it works if you only use one `@`.  I was originally using two at-signs @@ which I thought the documentation at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-system-variables.html required.  How am I misinterpreting the documentation?

```
class db {
    private static $instance = NULL;
    private function __construct() {}   //Make private
    private function __clone(){}   //Make private
    public static function db() //Get instance of DB
    {
        if (!self::$instance)
        {
            self::$instance = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDB", 'myUsername', 'myPassword');
            self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            self::$instance->exec('SET @MySession1=123');
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}

db::db()->exec('SET @MySession2=321');

$stmt=db::db()->query('SELECT @MySession1 AS MySession1, @MySession2 AS MySession2');
$rs=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo("MySession1={$rs['MySession1']} MySession2={$rs['MySession2']}");
```

Comment: Does it work without PDO, just in console?

Comment: @YourCommonSense  Never tested, but I got it working with PDO.  As I indicated in my edited post, why does it work?

Comment: mysql manual tells: > The @@var_name syntax for system variables is supported for compatibility with some other database systems.

Comment: @hakre.  But it doesn't seem to work.  I am using MySQL 5.5.28.

Comment: Have you tried in Mysql console as well?

Comment: @hakre.  Yes, I tested at the console.  
`mysql> SET @@MySession2=321; ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'MySession2'` and then `mysql> SET @MySession2=321; Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)`

Comment: Okay, maybe this compatibility is not available with your Mysql server configuration or version.

Comment: `SET @@sort_buffer_size=1000000;` doesn't create an error, but `SET @@sort_buffer_sizeXXX=1000000;` does.

Comment: You can not create new system variables I bet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between server variables and user defined variables. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html for the description of user defined variables.